# ValueError: Image size of 2000x100000 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, google-colaboratory, valueerror

I am trying to plot 5000 images of dataset (pictures of cats and dogs) for an image classification. I am using google colab and even when I tried using pycharm it also shows the same error. I am using import matplotlib.pyplot as plt for my code. All of the images' dimensions are 512x512.

```
#Calculate the number of rows and columns for subplots. Plot the images
num_images = len(df_BW)
num_rows = (num_images - 1) // 10 + 1
num_cols = min(num_images, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, 10, figsize=(20, num_rows * 2))
for idx, (img, label) in enumerate(zip(df_BW['image'], df_BW['label'])):
    ax = axes[idx // 10, idx % 10]
    ax.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_title(label)

#Hide empty subplots
for i in range(num_images, num_rows * 10):
    axes.flatten()[i].axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The code works fine using 100 images (the highest images i have test) but when I tried 5000 image it says:

> ValueError: Image size of 2000x100000 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: You are asking for a figure that is 1000 inches tall.  The default dpi is 100.  So Matplotlib tries to make an image that is 100,000 pixels tall, which is too much for the renderer.  So you either need to reduce the height in inches of the figure (your figsize keyword) or choose a coarser dpi.

Answer (score 0):

The `10` running through your script is hard-coding the number of columns.
If you instead changed it to `20` then instead of 2000 x 100000 you'd make an image 4000 x 50000, which are both inside the 2^16 limit.

By the way, that suggests your images are actually 200 x 200 pixels, not 512x512?

(As another by the way, `num_cols` is defined but not used; you could delete it.)

Comment: I think the error is about the size of the overall figure, which defaults to 100 dpi.  I agree that having more columns and fewer rows, and adjusting the figsize to match should fix this.